# Stop refreshing when page finishes loading

Tags: android, jquery, swiperefreshlayout

I am asking for help, the problem is the refresh icon disappears before the page is fully loaded.

Here is the code and thanks in advance:

```
final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mWebView.reload();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.stopLoading();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);





                    }
                },150000);
```

The 150000 is the amount of time it keeps appearing on the screen , I tried removing it but the the following override codes was messed up.I am a beginner so sorry if the solution is simple .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to refresh the web-page via `SwipeRefreshLayout` and show loading until whole page finish up loading.

For that remove this

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mWebView.stopLoading();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);





                }
            },150000);
```

you are stop loading page after 15 secs by yourself this is not necessary.

Instead do the following

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

Note : Set the `WebViewClient` to know a event when page finished it's loading.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you do much for helping but sorry I am a begginer, what should i write in //do your stuff here

Comment: Cheers! Happy to help!